# After iOS 8.1, on all devices ScrollView goes upwards and not scrolling when tapping on alertview cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, ios8.3

I have a login screen Where there are two text fields for username and password. When email is incorrect then i moved down the keyboard and show the appropriate alert for the user. When i clicked on cancel button of alertview then alert view disappears and scroll view goes upwards. This issue only comes on devices after iOS 8.1. On iOS 8.1 and earlier, it works fine. I don't understand what is the exact cause? Below is the code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (txtActiveField == txtUsername) {
        [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (txtActiveField == txtPassword) {
        [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
        //[self loginViaEmail:self];
        [self performSelector:@selector(loginViaEmail:) withObject:btnLogin afterDelay:0.0];
    }

    return YES;}

-(IBAction)loginViaEmail:(id)sender{

    //[txtActiveField resignFirstResponder];
    if ([[txtUsername.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]] length] == 0)
    {
        [AppDelegate showWithTitle:title message:@"Please enter Username/Email for your account"];
    }
    else if ([txtPassword.text length] < 6)
    {
        if([[txtPassword.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]] length] == 0)
            [AppDelegate showWithTitle:title message:@"Please enter Password"];
        else
            [AppDelegate showWithTitle:title message:@"Password contain minimum 6 characters"];
    }


#pragma mark Show alert with message
+(void)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)msg
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the issue with Alert view. As from iOS 8, AlertViewController comes instead of alert view. Try using below code which works fine on iOS 8.4 and below version

```
if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                     {

                                     }];
        [alertVC addAction:cancelAction];

        [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController] presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```